# How i can make compatible with higher screen?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am design a html layout in 980px width for making it works in lower screen. I want to make it works fine in big screen but I have a problem with a layout.

When I try `CTRL+-- (minus)` to check in low resolution I found that the button in left goes to right and Background image with shadow go to right. Its' make my layout pity.

Example of other site they never have looking bad when I try `ctrl minus minus`.

Can someone help me to figure out how i make my layout then if i try `ctrl minus minus` it's not look bad.

Comment: Resize your browser window, don't use `CTRL+`.

Comment: You can use the web developer toolbar for Firefox to quickly toggle between smaller screen resolutions in your browser https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zooming is not the same as changing your screen resolution. Resizing your browser window, on the other hand, can be seen as equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for answer ! but i'm really unable to know your means. Could you clarify that my layout are work fine in Everywhere,Suppose i try CTRL +-- it's fine on every big site but i'm unable to do in my design. Please tell me how i can do this.

Comment: I have yet to see a browser that can accurately zoom the view. Just change the size of the window - you know, grab the edge of the window and drag it around.

Comment: @user1197366 Resizing your browser window means to use the mouse to drag the browser window frame border so that it does not take up your entire desktop. I would not think CTRL + - or + to zoom will break your layout. You might want to check your HTML closing and opening tags if this is the case.

Comment: You are right but i have element to show in background image and i have set element (images) in document body by giving them a padding to left and top. When i try CTRL +-- then the right element in right side in bgimage goes to left and left-side image overlap them so it's make rude design. Well Thanks @Jake and kolink.

Answer (score 1):

How is the size of your button declared? Is it in `px`, `em`, or percentage?

If you are using `em` or percentage (or none at all), try `px` instead to set a specific pixel width and height (and other dimensions such as padding, margins, etc.) This is called using "fixed" dimensions, and may solve the problem of things scaling incorrectly when you zoom.

If not, realize that when you use `control + zoom in/zoom out` it may or may not also be zooming the text, which can cause problems and is typically harder to fix.

Finally, realize that you are not approaching your problem correctly. To see how your website would render on a larger screen, simply make your *browser window larger* or test it on a computer with a bigger monitor.